# variable Panels image page element

Tags: media, panels

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to create a panel with a header image.

The way I'm planning to do this is to add a new Page element within panels called "Banner" (in this menu http://puu.sh/jfBbm/8c09cfe2fe.png).

Is it possible to have it so then when a user clicks the *"Add Panel -> Page Elements -> Banner -> **Chose image?**"* **or is it not possible to have a variable image with this way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install [Fieldable Panels Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldable_panels_panes) module. This module allows you to create different fields for Panels pane. Then go to `admin/structure/fieldable-panels-panes`, Click on *Manage Fields* of *Panes Pane*

[image]

Add an *image field*, It is going to be like this

[image]

Now click on `Add Entity` tab and create a new entity. You must also create a `Category` in `Reusability`, This *Category* will be displayed in the Panels Content menu, I called it *My own Panels Pane*

[image]

Now save it.

If you open a Panel and click on *Add content* the *My own Panels Pane* is available, click on it and select the content you created.

[image]

From the list of *Panels Pane* in *Fieldable Panels Pane* there is a direct link to edit this image. I mean this (for testing I created `3` entities ):

[image]

Now you can easily edit the image and use it's direct link.